# При обновлении данных в таблице визуальная часть не меняется

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

Обновил данные в таблице JTable, как сделать так, чтобы они обновились в окне?

```
public class ForecastGUI extends JFrame{

Container container;
ArrayList<JRadioButton> radioButtonsDays = new ArrayList<JRadioButton>();
final ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup();
JTable jTable;
ForecastTable forecastTable;

ForecastGUI(String cityName, int days, boolean isSimple, ArrayList<String> dates,
            Sinoptik sinoptik){
    super("Forecast for " + cityName);
    setBounds(200, 50, 500, 300);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    setRadioButtonsDays(days, dates);
    addRadioButtonsDays(container, days);

    forecastTable = new ForecastTable(sinoptik, dates.get(0));
    jTable = forecastTable.getWeatherTable();
    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
    jTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(470, 70));
    container.add(jScrollPane);

    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: не работает((((

Comment: Если что, TableModel не используется

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать repaint();. Если это JFrame объект, то должно помочь.

Comment: Не помогает. :(((

Comment: Лучше добавить `JPanel` и использовать `paintComponent` или `paint` и желательно отвести в отдельный поток `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решается добавлением DefaultTableModel.При работе с ней все обновляется автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Я для перерисовки (правда панели) использовал вот:

```
removeAll();
revalidate();
repaint();
```

попробуй, может поможет, а так скинул бы код

Comment: Код отрисовки подгрузил, затем jTable меняется, а обновленная таблица не показывается